# How can I replace nodejs require() code with javascript?

Tags: node.js, d3.js

I have a D3 Visual that I'm trying to make work that starts with loading 3 packages like so:

```
const d3 = require('d3')
const d3Sankey = require('d3-sankey')
const dscc = require ('@google/dscc')
```

Can I just download these packages myself and then replace them with any javascript that will load them in without using npm/nodejs ?

For example, I downloaded d3-sankey from here: https://github.com/d3/d3-sankey/releases/tag/v0.7.1

I've pasted the d3-sankey.js file into the same folder as my visual. But now, how do I replace the require() to load in this file?

Thank you

Comment: One way to deal with this is the use of [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) which let's you require modules in the browser much like you do on the server.

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I'm trying to avoid using node for now. On all the other visuals, I've built, I've been directly loading in the packages like so: <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>          Can I replace those require statements with script like that? But it's a js file that I'm editing and the code snippet I've been using is html.

Comment: try adding this after you load d3
 `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-sankey/0.7.1/d3-sankey.min.js" />`